# Unable to perform trace route (TP Link router)

Tags: networking

I've been a long time lurker here, posted on stackoverflow by accident. Someone was nice enough to direct me here.

Anyway, I had to ask a question since majority of the users on TP Link forums are inactive.

I have an ADSL2+ connection at my house, the modem provided by the ISP was trash, so I ordered a TP-Link TD-8840T ADSL2+ Modem/Router (non-Wireless).

Before the setup was as below:

ISP modem (D-Link 2750U) - TP Link WDR3500 Router (connected through blue WAN port). I was able to perform trace routes, without packet loss and timing out.

Ever since I bought the new TP Link modem and connected it to my TP Link router, through the blue WAN port, I can't perform trace routes. After hopping on the modem, it times out after that on every hop.

here's a copy:

```
  2 ms     2 ms     2 ms  192.168.1.1
   *        *        *     Request timed out.
   *        *        *     Request timed out.
   *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

And it keeps on going like this.

Some people said it had something to do with Double NAT, so I used my router as an Access Point and connected it to the modem through the yellow LAN port, however still can't perform trace routes. Weirdest part is, if I connect my laptop DIRECTLY to the modem through LAN cable, I still can't perform trace routes.

Really confused here. Would greatly appreciate if someone could help out here.

Thanks :)

Comment: Is everything working otherwise? This is fairly normal now days, a lot of servers and routing hops do not return a ping. Unless something isn't working I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @acejavelin traceroute does not rely on replies to ICMP echo requests.

Comment: @Daniel B, while it is true that the [traceroute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute) command found on Unix, Linux, and OS X systems sends [UDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) datagrams to high-numbered ports rather than using [ICMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol), the output shown by Murtaza12 appears to be from a Microsoft Windows tracert command, since the 3 times are followed by the IP address or "Request timed out." [That command does use ICMP echo requests and replies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute#Implementation).

Comment: @moonpoint Yes, but whatever is sent is just meant to trigger the "TTL Exceeded" message. That message is usually not blocked on properly configured routers. Blocking outgoing echo requests is also not a common policy.

Comment: Go though the setup of both boxes and see if you can find a setting that prevent ping from lan or wan side.

Comment: @acejavelin Everything else works fine, browsing, pinging the same server I was trying to do a trace route on also works fine.

Comment: @moonpoint Yes I am using Windows Command Prompt to perform a trace route. I also tried using WinMTR and that times out on every hop too.

Comment: @FrankSixteen I did a hard reset on both router and modem, searched long and hard for an option that blocks ping from both LAN or WAN. I think I found one, however both options were disabled, so technically pings aren't prevented, which is true. Since I CAN ping, but I can't perform a trace route.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I have the same problem TP-Link model `TL-WR543G`.